# How to add hyperbolic curve in lattice

Tags: r, curve, lattice, hyperbolic-function

Let's pretend I want to add an hyperbolic curve to this plot

```
data(cars)    
xyplot(dist ~ speed, cars)
```

Even though, such function won't fit data, the curve should be like the one you see in the picture. Could you please suggest to me the proper code?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the various components as a function provided to the `panel` parameter of [`xyplot()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/lattice/html/xyplot.html).

In this case we can use:

1. `panel.xyplot()` to plot the points.
2. `panel.lines()` for the horizontal line at the mean.
3. `panel.text()` for the label saying "mean".
4. `panel.curve()` for the hyperbolic function. As you've said it doesn't fit the data I've just eyeballed a function that looks similar. You can change this by editing the `fun` and `line_scale` parameters.

```r
xyplot(
    dist ~ speed,
    cars,
    panel = function(x, y, fun = sinh, line_scale = 5, text_scale = 1.2, from = 0, to = 25, ...) {
        panel.xyplot(x, y, col = "black")
        panel.lines(x = seq(from, to), y = mean(x), col = "red", lwd = 2)
        panel.text(min(x) * text_scale, mean(x) * text_scale, "mean", col = "red")
        panel.curve(
            fun(x / line_scale),
            from = from,
            to = to,
            type = "l",
            col = "blue",
            lwd = 3
        )
    }
)
```

[image]

All these functions and their parameters are set it out in the `lattice` panel functions [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/lattice/html/panel.functions.html).